# Azure Search vs Suggestion api

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Does anybody know what is principal difference between the two?

For example, is request rate limit different for those Apis?

How is different fuzzy=true in Suggestion Api from *term~* in Search?

Can I use Search api as more fine-grained suggestions (with more options to configure)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The principal difference is that the Suggestions API is designed to be really fast finding phrase prefixes in documents (phrases where the last term is a prefix of a term). To achieve the same behavior in the Search API you'd have to [customize the lexical analysis process](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search/) to store prefixes of terms or phrases in the index for fast prefix matching. Alternatively, you could use the [suffix operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/simple-query-syntax-in-azure-search) '*' or [regex queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_regex) but they are much slower and you can't combine them with phrase queries. The fuzzy option has the same meaning in Suggest API and Search API. In the Search API you use the fuzzy operator '~' on any term of the query while in Suggest API it's automatically applied to the last term of the query if fuzzy=true.